# How do I select an element for a modal and also check that it is active using CSS

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, modal-dialog

I have the following code on a  web page for a popup modal:

```
<div id="ui--modal" data-modalguid="ghostModal-120028622297833437793" class="modules--reportActions-modal ui--modal-active" style="width: 600px; height: 310px; z-index: 2600001; left: 652px; top: 149px;">
```

I am trying to select the modal and verify that its active at the same time using CSS selectors

So far I only have (in C3) `c_copyReportPopup = By.CssSelector("#ui--modal")`

How do I verify that the element is active as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with looking at the style, something like this:

```
c_copyReportPopup = By.CssSelector("div#ui--modal[style*='block']")
```

I don't see the display style in your html above, but perhaps that was taken when the modal wasn't displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain append 2 css class selectors together.

```
 c_copyReportPopup = By.CssSelector("#ui--modal.ui--modal-active")
```